# how to delete the records which is inserted 1 day ago

Tags: sql, oracle

I dont have proper timestamp in table; is it possible to delete 1 day old logs even now?

I have a column name as SESSION_IN which is basically a VARCHAR datatype, and the value will be like

```
2013-10-15 02:10:27.883;1591537355
```

is there any way to trim the number after ; and is it possible to compare with "sysdate" identifier?

This SP should compare all the session IDs with current datetime and it should delete if it is older then 1 day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can igonre time part and convert date into required format somthing like this

```
SYSDATE - to_date('date_col','YYYY-DD-MM')
```

then you can perform operations.

Comment: Thanks Pravin, i am getting "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string" error.

Comment: select trunc(sysdate - (to_date(substr('2013-10-15 02:10:27.883;1591537355' , 1 , 10),'YYYY-MM-DD'))) from dual

Comment: Above query is giving me 38 days. Hope this is want you want

Answer (score 0):

Use the Substring function to extract the datetime portion from the record, then use convert to datetime to cast it to datetime, and then finally use datediff to check if it was inserted yesterday. Use all these caluses in a

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE ___ query
```

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle you could use something like this:

```
SELECT
    TRUNC(to_timestamp(SUBSTR('2013-10-15 02:10:27.883;1591537355',1,
    (
            SELECT
                    instr('2013-10-15 02:10:27.883;1591537355', ';')-1
            FROM
                    dual
    )
    ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF'))
FROM
    dual;
```

Which gives you just the date portion of your input string. Just subtract the amount of days you want to log at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Hope following query helps you:

```
Select Convert(Datetime,Substring('2013-10-15 02:10:27.883;1591537355',1,23)), DateDiff(dd,Convert(Datetime,Substring('2013-10-15 02:10:27.883;1591537355',1,23)),Getdate())
```

Comment: Many Thanks for you response :)

since i am trying this function for ORACLE 10g, its throwing error:

ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Please suggest me is there anything i need to change?